# Get story and all its comments in 1 query

Tags: php, join, mysqli

I am trying to create an PHP api in which I am trying to retrieve news storys and all its comments and send it as json.

Here is what i have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fb_clubnews WHERE clubid='$groupId' AND ori_newsid = 0 ORDER BY newsid DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $storId = $row["newsid"];

        $commentArray = array();

        $wallAray[] = array("author"=>$row["userid"],
                                "story"=>$row["news"],
                                "date"=>$row["date"],
                                "time"=>$row["time"],
                                "matchid"=>$row["fk_match_id"],
                                "comments"=>$commentsArray);
    }
}
```

My issue is, that I would like to avoid creating a sql inside an sql and loop through it?! The second inside sql would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fb_clubnews WHERE ori_newsid = $storId ORDER BY newsid DESC";
```

How do I get the $commentArray filled up with comments.

My DB Structure for fb_clubnews looks like this:

```
int newsid (autoincrement),
int userid,
text news,
int data,
int time,
int matchid,
int ori_newsid
```

Hoping for help on this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Share DB structure...then it will be more good to help.....

Comment: See edited question

Comment: What is the structure of your comments table and where comments are storing ?

Comment: I do not have a comments table. Both main story and comments are in the same table. Story is a comment if it has a ori_newsid > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, A.newsid as main_news_id FROM fb_clubnews A LEFT JOIN fb_clubnews B ON B.ori_newsid = A.newsid  WHERE A.clubid='$groupId' AND A.ori_newsid = 0 ORDER BY A.newsid DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$wallAray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $storId = $row["main_news_id"];
        if(array_key_exists($storId, $wallAray)) {
            $commentArray[] = $wallAray;
        } else {
            $wallAray[$storId] = array();
            $commentArray = array();
        }

        $wallAray[] = array("author"=>$row["userid"],
                            "story"=>$row["news"],
                            "date"=>$row["date"],
                            "time"=>$row["time"],
                            "matchid"=>$row["fk_match_id"],
                            "comments"=>$commentsArray);
    }
}
```